# How to remove gain and offset errors from ADC logic?

Tags: adc

I have a 3-bit converter with ideal LSB of 50 mV. The following table shows the non-ideal logical values.

I need to remove gain and offset errors from the codes below.

I read on the internet that one step to remove gain error is to calculate a new LSB, by doing an average:

AVG_LSB = (363 mV - (-2 mV)) / (8-1) = 52.14 mV

If I calculate the table using this new LSB (NEW gain) I get table 2 shown below.
Did it remove the gain error? If so, then why is it called removing gain error?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You just did a two-point linear regression. You could be using all 8 measurement points instead to achieve lower linearization error. Please read on [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)

Comment: I talking about gain error in ADC if its similar to linear regression then cool but i am asking about the gain error

Comment: If you're trying to explain, through a fitted line, the ADC counts versus input voltage, then this is by definition a linear regression. In the terminology you're using, "removing ADC gain error" = fitting the most appropriate line slope; "removing offset error" = fitting the y-intercept

Answer (score 2):

A old but good application note from TI: Understanding Data Converters

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa013/slaa013.pdf

They show the dominant errors in ADC's.

Most of them you can measure and compensate with a Lookup Table, Interpolation or simple multiply/add operations... but you will loose full scale range in most/all cases, so I guess your fun with correcting a 3bit Converter will be limited.